# why Xcode can not find finder.h

Tags: objective-c, xcode, finder

I'm trying to use FinderApplication and so I want to import Finder.h in my code, but Xcode tell me it can not find the Finer.h.
can anybody tell me how to use FinderApplication ? my platform is mountain lion and Xcode 5.0
thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do with Finder app?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a "FinderApplication" is. You may want to explain that a bit further.

Nonetheless, in order to use Finder.h, you need to ensure that the CoreServices framework is included in your Xcode project.

Don't worry about trying to import the Finder.h file directly, though. It's imported by CarbonCore, which in turn is imported by CoreServices. If you need an #import statement, just use

```
#import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: I just saw this class from <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560757/get-path-to-selected-file-in-finder>. I have added this header file actually, which did include Finder.h, but still can not find this class.

Comment: But did you add the CoreServices framework as well? Just adding the #import isn't enough.

Comment: yes, I added this framework first, then I added the header file. anyway, thanks:)